# How should a website handle signup for two types of accounts?

Tags: layout, buttons, signup-signon, homepage

For instance, say a site is for merchants and consumers; people should either sign up as a merchant or a consumer – they require two different forms located on different pages. From the home page, should I have two different buttons, each to the appropriate signup page? Or, in an effort to reduce clutter and because more consumers than merchants will sign up, do I make a large "Sign Up" button front and center on the home page for consumers, then just have a smaller link in the top menu that says "Merchant sign up"?

Comment: Could you not have a single "Sign Up" button, and in the sign up process, have a check box for merchants?

Comment: How different is the merchant signup process compared to the consumer one? Do they need to provide more or different information?

Comment: @JonW They are quite different, however the merchant signup is, for the most part, the consumer form plus some more information.

Comment: What if I am a consumer and a merchant? Do I need to use two different accounts?

Comment: @peterchen I have thought about this one, and the way I currently have it coded is so that you must have a unique email address across the entire service. So in other words, currently, yes – you will need two different accounts.

Comment: @SSumner you raise a very good point; I could just have a single sign up form where I collect information needed for both accounts – first name, email address, and password. Then I can have a "Submit" button or a "I am a merchant" button, the latter of which would fade in some more form fields. I just have to make sure it is clear, and I will have to figure out what to do if a user clicks on it accidentally.

Comment: Just wondering: is there a reason to make customers sign up at all, ahead of time? You could consider only giving customers the option (not obligation!) to sign up at checkout. That would also take care of your issue, as the only sign up you need to display is that for merchants.

Comment: @zch: In general I would expect to sign up once (maybe as a consumer), and have an extra step to unlock merchant functionality. But maybe that doesn't work well for your site.

Comment: @André thank you for the comment. I have thought about this, but ultimately decided that, because consumers will be making frequent, small purchases, it will be better for them and me to only ask for credit card information once. They are able to browse the site without an account, but when it comes to making purchases, I have decided that they need an account.

Comment: @peterchen That makes sense, and I have seen that implementation before on the majority of websites – you make an Apple ID and then can later fill out more info to become a developer, for example. However like you said, I don't know that that would be the best option, here, from a usability and developmental standpoint. Though thank you for the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have one prominent signup button on the homepage. As there are more consumers than merchants, display the consumers form, but at the top of the form create a link for merchants, something like:

Are you a merchant? Sign up here.

Which would then take you to the merchant signup.

Or for something a little more elegant, if a merchant clicks the link: fade out the consumer form and fade in the merchant form.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend going with a prominent sign up button but on opening the form, allow the user to choose the form he needs by use of a radio button.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5n3zz.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

It would also be good if dynamically a message can be shown which informs the user which form he has selected just in case he has made a mistake

Answer (score 1):

Should it be possible, try to provide one type of account with additional rights for the merchants. This will reduce users confusion I think.

If this is not what you can do, I would go the second way you proposed: bigger signup button for regular users and a link for merchants. How much you can or should reduce the link depends on the merchants' awareness of the system. If they are educated to use it, even a link in footer will do. Otherwise you can try to make the link look like it directs to a completely separate section, e.g. You can put it in the top menu to the very right, add different background and name it "merchants section".

Comment: That is what I am thinking; I will need a top menu that has links to 'About' and 'Signin,' so maybe next to there can be a 'Merchant Signup' button that redirects to their form.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on the frequency of each signup type. A lot of websites (and companies by extension) do not have that many merchants or partners to warrant programming separate signup screens, with the merchants or partners being entered manually and an unobtrusive to main navigation login link for them exists. Another way to look at it is that (typically) the merchant website is entirely different to that of consumers, tying up the two from the outset can put you on the wrong track which you fight all the way.